# How do I add a delegate to a document based application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates

I cannot figure out how to add the delegate `NSTextViewDelegate` to my document based application. The `@implementation` is :

```
@interface MPODocument :  NSPersistentDocument
```

And I cannot seem to add `NSTextViewDelegate`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its this easy !

```
@interface MPODocument :  NSPersistentDocument<NSTextViewDelegate>
```

Comment: Thanks! I just wasn't seeing it.